# Issues with ssh-add

Tags: ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am attempting to add an ssh key using ssh-add. Upon running ssh-add ~/.ssh/insertkeynamehere I am prompted with:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

After doing some research it would appear as if this is because my ssh-agent is not running but ps -ef | grep ssh-agent indicates otherwise:

```
cdm       1760  1727  0 14:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=classic-gnome
```

Even after running:

```
exec ssh-add bash
```

And seeing:

```
cdm       1760  1727  0 14:35 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=classic-gnome
cdm       2903     1  0 14:45 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
```

This problem still seems to persist. Any help would be much appreciated and if you need to see anymore console output let me know and I'll be happy to post.

*Note I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ `eval ssh-agent`
```

Which echo series of environment variables making ssh-add to work.
Just paste that into your terminal and:

```
$ exec ssh-agent bash
```

Then:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/insertkeynamehere
```

source: [Ubuntu manpages: ssh-add](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ssh-agent.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after running 'eval ssh-agent' I received: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-fSYxVokg3559/agent.3559; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=3560; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3560;

After running the add again the same 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.'

Comment: Then, try again the "exec ssh-agent bash" ?

I have edited my Answer.

Comment: Still no luck even with the exec ssh-agent bash.

Comment: Strange, did you paste the output of 'eval ssh-agent' into your terminal before using ssh-add ?

Comment: Oops, didn't paste in the output, it appears to be working now, thanks for your help.