# ssh-add under cygwin

Tags: cygwin, ssh-agent

I'm having trouble with ssh-agent under cygwin.  The crazy part is that it was working, but stopped after a reboot one day.  Here is an example:

```
sthomas@sthomas-tcg ~
$ keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa

KeyChain 2.6.8; http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/keychain/
Copyright 2002-2004 Gentoo Foundation; Distributed under the GPL

 * Initializing /home/sthomas/.keychain/sthomas-tcg-sh file...
 * Initializing /home/sthomas/.keychain/sthomas-tcg-csh file...
 * Initializing /home/sthomas/.keychain/sthomas-tcg-fish file...
 * Starting ssh-agent
 * Adding 1 ssh key(s)...
Enter passphrase for /home/sthomas/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/sthomas/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/sthomas/.ssh/id_rsa)


sthomas@sthomas-tcg ~
$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

sthomas@sthomas-tcg ~
$ ssh stage
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sthomas/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I found this user who is having the exact same problem as me

[Issues with ssh-add](https://serverfault.com/questions/325402/issues-with-ssh-add)

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment there.  I tried following his instructions but the first step is not working for me:

```
sthomas@sthomas-tcg ~
$ `eval ssh-agent`
-bash: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ejseksys5348/agent.5348;: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what is going wrong here?  The file does exist but the missing filename changes on each execution.

```
sthomas@sthomas-tcg ~
$ ls /tmp/ssh-ejseksys5348/agent.5348
/tmp/ssh-ejseksys5348/agent.5348
```

Comment: Hmm.  Can you do `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-ejseksys5348/agent.5348` and then do the `ssh-add`?

Comment: @cjc wouldn't that only be a temporary fix?

Comment: Simple question, but is the `ssh-agent` process running?

Comment: @mgorven The OP's post suggests it's running, since he ran the command and there's a resulting socket file. The problem is to get ssh-agent's environmental variables exported so that ssh can see them.

Comment: @cjc Based on "the missing filename changes on each execution" I suspected that the process wasn't hanging around, but now I see that `ssh-agent` doesn't handle an existing running agent nicely and so this is expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, that other Serverfault.com answer has a typo.

The right thing you want to run is:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

`ssh-agent` spits out a bunch of shell statements to set environmental variables.  The `eval` runs them in the current shell.  You can invoke `ssh-agent` that way, or run `ssh-agent` and then copy-paste its output into your current shell for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

fixed another aspect of this message : I imported a key from a mint VM to cygwin. I used nano without nowrap and copied my public key over 3 lines instead of 1. 
I had to put in on an unique line and it finaly worked with eval.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you commenting on an answer on a completely different question?